# Método POST no devuelve nada

Tags: c#, api, windows-forms, post

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que genero y consumo una API a través de Spring Tool Suite.

En dicha API tengo un controlador para que me devuelva un objeto Profesor con ciertos filtros (esto funciona bien porque está comprobado a través de postman). La función es esta:

```
@PostMapping("/adminlogin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAdminLogin(@RequestHeader String user, @RequestHeader String password) {
        Predicate<Profesor> byLogin = p -> p.getUser().equals(user) && p.getPassword().equals(password);
        Profesor profesor = this.profesorRepositorio.findAll().stream().filter(byLogin).findFirst().orElse(null);
        if(profesor != null) {
            List<Profesor> profesoresConPerfiles2y4 = this.profesorRepositorio.findProfesoresConPerfiles2y4();
            if (profesoresConPerfiles2y4.contains(profesor)) {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(profesor);
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Acceso denegado");
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Acceso denegado");
    }
```

Para consumir la API en mi aplicación, uso una clase genérica llamada WebConsumer, en la que creo un método PostAsync para usarlo de manera genérica (en donde creo que tengo aquí el problema, pero no sabría decirlo):

```
public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url, string usuario, string password)
        {
            object data = new { user = usuario, password = password };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                T responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseJson);
                return responseObject;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ApplicationException($"Error al obtener el recurso: {response.StatusCode}");
            }
        }
```

Este método se llama a través de una clase estática manejadora donde le paso los parámetros que quiero usar en dicho POST:

```
public static async Task<dynamic> ObtenerAdmin(string user, string password)
        {
            WebConsumer wb = new WebConsumer();

            Profesor admin = await wb.PostAsync<dynamic>("127.0.0.1:8080/adminlogin", user, password);
            if (admin != null)
            {
                return admin;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Y desde el main() llamo a dicha clase manejadora para obtener un Profesor. Si es nulo no hace nada, si no lo es pasa el login:

```
private void btnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (UsuarioValido())
            {
                fmrGuardiasMDI aplicacion = new fmrGuardiasMDI(profesor);
                aplicacion.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error en el inicio de sesión", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtUsuario.Clear();
                txtContraseña.Clear();
            }

        }

        private bool UsuarioValido()
        {
            string user = this.txtUsuario.Text;
            string pass = MD5Formatter(this.txtContraseña.Text);

            dynamic result = Herramientas.ObtenerAdmin(user, pass);
            Profesor profe = result as Profesor;
            
            if (profe != null)
            {
                this.profesor = profe;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

El caso es que en ningún momento me devuelve un objeto que no sea nulo, por tanto nunca podría iniciar la sesión y no tengo ni idea del cómo ni por qué pasa esto. No se si es cosa de la API, si es cosa de la clase WebConsumer y su método PostAsync... Estoy muy perdido.

Comment: Recomendacion, es vez de realizar _new HttpClient();_ dale una mirada a IHttpClientFactory [IHttpClientFactory con .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)

Answer (score 0):

Nada, ya lo tengo, tenía que pasar la url absoluta en ObtenerAdmin. Es decir:

```
public static async Task<dynamic> ObtenerAdmin(string user, string password)
        {
            WebConsumer wb = new WebConsumer();

            Profesor admin = await wb.PostAsync<dynamic>("http://127.0.0.1:8080/adminlogin", user, password);
            if (admin != null)
            {
                return admin;
            }

            return null;
        }
```